# Question on 1-1 & onto function

Tags: functions, relations

While I was studying relations & functions I came across with this question which I can't figure out the meaning of it. Please help.

Let $X$ be the set of all strings of finite length consisting of $0$'s and $1$'s. The function $h:X\to\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ (non-negative integers) is defined by $h(x)=n-\bar{x}$ where $n$ is the length of $x$ and $\bar{x}$ is the number of $1$'s in $x$.

How shall I determine whether $h$ is one-one and onto?

Comment: [Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Comment: Check each separately.  First check 1:1, go by the definition of 1:1.  Then check onto, again by definition, essentially showing the function can cover the entire range... http://www.regentsprep.org/Regents/math/algtrig/ATP5/OntoFunctions.htm

Comment: What do you mean when you say you can't figure out the meaning of the question?  Which part of it specifically are you not understanding?

Comment: @GuySirton I can't understand what the question says."strings of finite length consisting of 0'sand 1's"

Answer (score 3):

We explain what the function $h$ does. After that you will not find the problem hard.

Let $x$ be the string $011000$. This string has length $6$, and has $2$ $1$'s. So $h(x)=6-2=4$. Let $x$ be the string $0000000$. This has length $7$, and no $1$'s, so $h(x)=7-0=7$. Strings of any length are allowed. With a bit of patience, you can find $h(x)$ where $x=11110010010100101001010010101001010100111100000$.

Note that all values of $h(x)$ are non-negative integers, since the length of a string cannot be less than the number of $1$'s in the string.

Now that you know what $h(x)$ does, it should not be hard to come up with two specific **distinct** strings $x$ and $y$ such that $h(x)=h(y)$. When you have done that, you  will have shown that the function $h$ is not one to one.

Now that you know what $h$ does, it should also not be hard to show that $h$ is onto. For concreteness, first think of how to make a string $x$ such that $h(x)=17$.

**Remark:** Your responses can become nearly instantaneous if you think about the following question: If we take the length of a string, and subtract the number of $1$'s, what do we get?

Comment: I got it now. Thank you.:)

Comment: You are welcome. It was just a question of making concrete what the mathematical language was saying. It will  often be the case that as soon as you find out what's really going on, you are much of the way to a solution.